# Check if message is empty before displaying UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

`UIAlertView` is widely used in the code.

I would like to check all alert view message before displaying it.

I have written a method in a category of `UIAlertView`.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to fix this in one place and there by all the alertview would automatically call it before displaying it. (example - like overriding some method)

Note - I have already a method for this, but I don't want to change the code manually in all the places, instead I am looking for a sleek solution if that is possible such that I change in one place (like override a method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a category on UIAlertView and provide a method that checks first if the message exists, then shows:

```
@implementation UIAlertView (OnlyShowIfMessageExists)

- (void)override_show
{
    if(self.message.length)
    {
        [self override_show];
    }
}
```

It is calling override_show and not show, because those methods will be swizzled.

Implement the +(void)load method as well in the category, and swizzle your method with the show method:

```
+(void)load
{
    SEL origSel = @selector(show);
    SEL overrideSel = @selector(override_show);

    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIAlertView.class, origSel);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIAlertView.class, overrideSel);

    if(class_addMethod(UIAlertView.class, origSel, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod)))
    {
        class_replaceMethod(UIAlertView.class, overrideSel, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    }
    else
    {
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
    }
}

@end
```

Now, all calls to show on a UIAlertView will be using your method override_show.

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html

Comment: Is it safe to swizzle `UIAlertView` ? If it is then it seems super sleek !!

Comment: I just tested it and it seemed to work. Not guaranteed to always work forever.

Comment: Ensure `#import <objc/runtime.h>` is added before you compile the above code